# Convert MYSQL Timestamp to JavaScript Date in IE11 Issue

Tags: javascript, date, internet-explorer

I have received Timestamp from MYSQL to Javascript through Json.

Now I want to do some operations on it for that I had done as shown below.

```
                  var ch = '2015-08-15 21:41:47.0'; // timestamp from mysql
                  var date = new Date(ch);   // It worked fine on Chrome&Firefox
```

But in IE it's returning NaN. I Had googled it and I found that the date string representation should be an RFC2822 or ISO 8601.

So I tried to make it look like `new Date(1995, 11, 17, 3, 24, 0)` for that I have done as shown below

```
              var tstamp = '2015-08-15 21:41:47.0';
              tstamp = tstamp.replace(/-|:|\s/g, ","); 
              var date = Date.parse(ch);
```

But still I am getting NaN. Any Help.

Answer (score 0):

try splitting and re-arrange

```
   var tstamp = '2015-08-15 21:41:47.0';
   tstamp = tstamp.split(/[- :]/);

   console.log(tstamp);
```

Or you can modify date format in mysql OR in server side script.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this exact problem myself.
The default mysql date format returns the error `lid Date, Invalid Date` when trying to use it with `new Date()` in ie11, but works fine in firefox and chrome.

The answer is actually very simple. You just need to make the mysql date string look like an iso format date string. Which is supported in ie11.

(seconds, milliseconds and Z params are optional)
iso format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`.

So instead of using your mysql date string like this:

```
mysqlTime = "2017-08-01 10:19:08";
new Date(mysqlTime);
```

You can simply add a `T` before the time string like this:

```
mysqlTime = "2017-08-01 10:19:08";
mysqlTime = mysqlTime.replace(/ /, "T");
new Date(mysqlTime);
```

And now it will work fine in ie9+ browsers. ISO Date Format is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 standards mode and Quirks mode. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/date-and-time-strings-javascript#ISO

Hope this helps.